# laravel project with nginx errors

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have upload my laravel project to remote linux host .This project works well on my local windows homestead.But when I put it on linux host,it does not work .
The project root is :/var/www/html/blog . the nginx config as follwing:

```
`server
    {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.antichina.us ;
        index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
        root  /var/www/html/blog/public;

       # include other.conf;
        #error_page   404   /404.html;

        # Deny access to PHP files in specific directory
        #location ~ /(wp-content|uploads|wp-includes|images)/.*\.php$ { deny all; }

        include enable-php.conf;

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }



        access_log off;
    }
`
```

when I visit the project with the domain,(http://mydomain),it give an http 500 error. but when I set the root as /var/www/html/blog in the nginx config file, the index page of the project is working by visit: http://mydomain/public,  other routes are all return 404 error.

I have tried my method,but it seems none is working.Any on ecould help me?thank you !

Comment: Your title says there are errors, but you haven't said what they are.

Comment: when I visit the project with the domain,(http://mydomain),it give an http 500 error. but when I set the root as /var/www/html/blog in the nginx config file, the index page of the project is working by visit: http://mydomain/public, other routes are all return 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your nginx config

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Your index line only needs to this also:

```
index index.php;
```

What's in this this file?

```
include enable-php.conf;
```

Comment: in the enable-php.conf  file:
`location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)
        {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `fastcgi` and not `php-fpm`?

Comment: actually I know little about the configration of nginx.

Comment: Do you have access to the linux host command line? If so type `ps aux | grep php-fpm`. You should see something like `1 root   php-fpm master process`.

Comment: root       962  0.0  0.4 151436  4892 ?        Ss   15:48   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)                                      
www        963  0.0  0.4 151436  4300 ?        S    15:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                                              
www        964  0.0  0.4 151436  4296 ?        S    15:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                                              
root       981  0.0  0.0   6380   700 pts/1    S+   16:08   0:00 grep php-fpm

Comment: There you go. Nginx is configured to use fastcgi but php-fpm is running, so I'd assume that's what you want use.